# R : how to use variables for vector indices?

Tags: r, variables, indexing

I'm new user of R, and trying to generate a k-moving average graph with sine function which involves random number(in range [-0.5,+0.5]) noise. 
So what I have to do is calculate a mean of consecutive (2*k+1) elements in noised-sine vector but however, the code with "HELP" below, it's not working as I expected... :(
The code seems to calculate the mean of 1 through (i-k)th element.
What's wrong with it? Help please!

```
set.seed(1)

x = seq(0,2*pi,pi/50)
sin_graph <- sin(x)
noise <- runif(101, -0.5, 0.5)
sin_noise <- sin_graph + noise

plot(x,sin_noise, ylim=c(-2,2))
lines(x,sin_graph, col="red")

k<-1
MA<-0

while (k<=1){
  i <- k+1
  MA_vector <- rep(NA, times=101)
  while (i<=101-k){
    MA_vector[i] <- mean(sin_noise[i-k:i+k]) #HELP!
    i <- i+1
  }
  print(MA_vector)
  plot(x, MA_vector, ylim=c(-2,2))
  lines(x,sin_graph, col="red")
  k<-k+1
}
```

Comment: Perhaps with as.numeric(i-k):as.numeric(i+k). Also, maybe the functino rollaply might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, it's substracting a vector of `k:i` from `i` and then adding `k`. `:` takes precedent over mathematical operators. By using brackets (see code below), it evaluates `i-k` and `i+k` and creates a vector with min and max as results of the evaluations. I get another smooth function.

```
MA_vector[i] <- mean(sin_noise[(i-k):(i+k)])
```